# Lightswitch 2011 Concurrency Control

Tags: optimistic-concurrency, pessimistic-locking

I 've got two question.

1. Does Lightswitch **2011** support also pessimistic concurency control? If so, how?
2. Does optimistic control support ROWVERSION column on table from external data source or use only state of row (using original values)?

Thank you for response.

Answer (score 0):

1. Lightswitch 2011 supports only optimistic concurrency. Hovewer, I integrated pessimistic concurrency into Lightswitch succesfully. I used Coarse-Graind Lock from Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture (Martin Fowler) with Entity Framework witch already contains UnitOfWork (ObjectContext) and Repository (ObjectSet). Acquire, Release and Checking of Lock using ExecuteStoreCommand and ExecuteStoreQuery from EF. Custom RIA Service with CRUD operations for Root and Children entities was implemented.
2. Optimistic control with ROWVERSION is possible with custom RIA Service which use model from EF.